# Plotting means with facet_grid in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have the following `data.frame`:

```
values<-runif(72)
factorA<-rep(c(rep('a',9),rep('b',9)),2)
criterion<-rep(rep(c(rep('1/4',3),rep('1/2',3),rep('2/3',3)),4),2)
case<-rep(c(rep('1',18),rep('2',18)),2)
samp<-rep(c('10','20','30'),24)
datasets<-c(rep('1',36),rep('2',36))
df<-data.frame(values,factorA,criterion,case,samp,datasets)
```

I want to use `ggplot` to plot the means of `values` between the two `datasets`. If I consider only the subset `datasets='1'`, I want to build the following plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(directlabels)
ggplot(subset(df,datasets %in% '1'),aes(x=samp,y=values,group=criterion))+
     geom_line(aes(linetype = criterion),size=1)+
     facet_grid(case~factorA,scales='free',space='free')+
     geom_dl(aes(label = criterion),method=list(dl.combine('first.qp','last.qp')))
```

which produces [image]

as `values` were obtained randomly.

I want to obtain exactly this plot, but where each line represents the trajectories of the means between the two `datasets`, for the corresponding values. For example, in the panel `('a','1')`, the point on the line `criterion='1/4'` and abscissa `samp='10'` must be the mean of the corresponding values of `datasets` 1 and 2; the point on the line `criterion='1/4'` and abscissa `samp='20'` must be the mean of the corresponding values of `datasets` 1 and 2, and so on and for each panel. How can I achieve that? I tried with `stat_summary()` but with no success...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use dplyr's group_by and summarize to accomplish what you describe. 
1) Group the df by all variables except the dataframe column
and 
2) calculate the mean of the values column for each group:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(directlabels)
set.seed(1)
values<-runif(72)
factorA<-rep(c(rep('a',9),rep('b',9)),2)
criterion<-rep(rep(c(rep('1/4',3),rep('1/2',3),rep('2/3',3)),4),2)
case<-rep(c(rep('1',18),rep('2',18)),2)
samp<-rep(c('10','20','30'),24)
datasets<-c(rep('1',36),rep('2',36))
df<-data.frame(values,factorA,criterion,case,samp,datasets)

#calculate means of the value columns by group
df_means <- df %>% 
  group_by(case, factorA, samp, criterion) %>% 
  summarize(mean_value = mean(values))

ggplot(df_means,aes(x=samp,y=mean_value,group=criterion))+
  geom_line(aes(linetype = criterion),size=1)+
  facet_grid(case~factorA,scales='free',space='free')+
  geom_dl(aes(label = criterion),method=list(dl.combine('first.qp','last.qp')))
```

Check if desired output is correct:

```
> df %>% 
+ filter(criterion == '1/4', factorA == 'a', samp == '10', case == '1')
     values factorA criterion case samp datasets
1 0.2655087       a       1/4    1   10        1
2 0.7942399       a       1/4    1   10        2
> mean(c(0.2655087, 0.7942399))
[1] 0.5298743
> df_means %>% 
+   filter(criterion == '1/4', factorA == 'a', samp == '10', case == '1')
# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Groups:   case, factorA, samp [1]
  case  factorA samp  criterion mean_value
  <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>          <dbl>
1 1     a       10    1/4            0.530
```

Comment: Yes, I was also exploring this solution because it seems easier: first compute the means of the desired cases and then do the plot. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Thank you for the update ;-) I was checking if the output is correct ;-)

Comment: Never hurts to double check